# What's artificial intelligence?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm a bit confused about artificial intelligence.

I understand it as the capability of a machine to learn new things, or do different things without actually executing code (already written by someone).

In SO I see many threads about A.I. in games, but IMO that is not an A.I. Because if it is every software even a print command should be called A.I. In games there is just code that is executed. I would call it pseudo-AI.

Am I wrong? Should be also this considered as A.I.?

Comment: See [Turing test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test). Smart people have been thinking about this problem for well over 60 years.

Comment: On SO there are many people adding the AI tag when they try to program their first game (which should at one point in the future include something they think is AI) and have a question about their failure to draw a sprite on the screen.

Comment: An algorithm that attempts to mimic human decision making skills or even beyond that can be called A. I. It's also true that most computer games have A. I. regardless if its good or not. To tell if its a good A.I or not is subjective to a persons appreciation or standards. Some say Neural Networks is the real A.I. but how close is it mimic human brain compared to a simple chess program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Minsky and McCarthy, both considered founders of AI, say that artificial intelligence is anything done by a program or a machine that if a human did the same activity, we would say the human had to apply intelligence to accomplish the task."

A more modern definition is to turn this on its head:

Artificial intelligence is anything done by a program or a machine that if a human did the same activity, we would say the human did not need to apply intelligence to accomplish the task.

Intelligence is the ability to do the things that don't require reasoning. Things like understanding and generating language, sequencing your leg muscles as you walk across the floor, or enjoying a symphony. You don't stop to reason for any of those things. You *Understand*. INTUITIVELY, how to interpret things in your visual field, language, and all other sensory input. And you can do the right thing without reasoning. You can easily prepare all of your breakfast without any reasoning. :-)

Doing things that "require thought" or reasoning, like playing chess or solving integrals are things that computers can already do.

This misunderstanding about what intelligence really is has cost us 60 years and a million man-years of banging our head against the wall.

Deep learning is the currently most popular expression of an alternative path to a "better kind of AI". Artificial Intuition is a special branch of Deep Learning tailored at understanding text.

The easiest way to know whether you are dealing with classical (futile) or modern AI is whether the system requires you to supply *any* models of the world (MOTW). Any MOTW means the AI is limited to operate in the domain specified by the MOTW and is therefore not a **general** intelligence. Also, anything with a MOTW is typically not designed to extend that model; this is a *very difficult* task.

Better to start from a Model of the Mind (MOTM) or a Model of Learning. These can be derived either from neuroscience (difficult) or from epistemology (much easier). A well done MOTM can then learn anything it needs to know to solve problems in any domain.

The main problem for most is to find what's called "a domain-independent method for determining saliency".  In other words, all intelligences, natural or artificial, have to spend most of their time answering the question "what matters".

Google my name and "AI" for more.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia says this:

> Artificial intelligence (AI) is the intelligence of machines and the branch of computer science that aims to create it.
>
> AI textbooks define the field as "the study and design of intelligent agents"
> <sup>[[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning)]</sup>, where an intelligent agent is a system that perceives its environment and takes actions that maximize its chances of success.

What you are considering is more specifically referred to as [Machine Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning), which is indeed a subbranch of AI. As you can see from the second sentence above, however, the "AI" considered in games also fits perfectly well into this definition.

Of course, the actual line between what is AI, and what not, is quite blurry. This is also due to the fact, that everyone and his mother believes to know what "AI" means.

I suggest you grab yourself a more scientific book (say the [classical Russel,Norvig](http://www.amazon.de/Artificial-Intelligence-Modern-Approach-Second/dp/0130803022)) to get a more thorough grasp on the different fields that are present under the huge roof of what we simply refer to as "AI".

Answer (score 4):

[Minsky](http://web.media.mit.edu/~minsky/) and [McCarthy](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/), both considered founders of AI, say that artificial intelligence is anything done by a program or a machine that if a human did the same activity, we would say the human had to apply intelligence to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

Frank and Kirt sum up the academic field of AI pretty well. Any difficulty there is defining AI reflects the more general problem of defining real intelligence. If AI has proved anything, it's that we have precious little idea what intelligence is, how amazing organisms are at solving problems, and how difficult it is to get machines to achieve the same results.

As for the use of the term AI in the video games industry, your confusion justified. The prospect of intelligent characters in games is so compelling, that the term long ago took on a life of its own as marketing jargon. However, AI is really just a poorly chosen name for the solving of problems that computers find hard and people find easy. And in that sense, there is plenty of genuine AI work going on in the games industry.

Take a look at [AIGameDev.com](http://AIGameDev.com/) for a taste of what is currently considered noteworthy in AI game development.

Answer (score 0):

The most important aspect of AI as I believe is 'curiosity'. Intelligence comes from this very fact that it is a result of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no precise definition of AI because intelligence itself is relative and hard to define, this is due to the fact that many fields (ancient and modern) such as Philosophy and Neuroscience serve as the foundations of AI. It depends on what your AI is expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

Artificial Intelligence is the attempt to create intelligence from a computer program.

Regardless if its a toy program or neural science, as long as a program is able to mimic human problem-solving skills or even go beyond it, is called Artificial Intelligence.

Of course, the expectation of computer scientists on how capable a program (or machine) is to solve problems in time increases. Playing tic-tac-toe programs before is considered intelligent until chess programs where invented. Then now we are attempting to mimic how human brain through neural networks.

A.I for layman's now a day's is applied in most computer games. It's also used in most machines, like in airplane for autopilot, NASA's explorer on Mars called curiosity (2012), who's able to detect terrain obstacles and move around it.

Comment: I agree with your definition somewhat. In a book by **Blay Whitby** called **A beginner's guide to AI** he says "AI is the study of human intelligence and the attempt to find ways to engineer the intelligent behaviour of humans in machines."

Answer (score -2):

Very tricky stuff A.I. Its like if you design a mind that replies to all the right questions with all the answers, is it A.I. Or just a talking encyclopedia. What if you can teach the A.I. by simply talking to it, do you then consider that A.I. with a mind, or again just a program. Perhaps the question or answer is if someone someday makes a machine that looks human, acts human, and thinks its human. And then see if others feel the same, that its human, if they dont know its not. And then what if it passes that test. You see its not really about is the machine conscious, or does it have a mind as those will never be truly answered. Its all about does it "seem conscious" act conscious, act like it has a mind, given thats as close as humanity will ever get to understanding that riddle. If a machine acts like it cares, and does helpful things thats all that really matters, not the rest of unseen picture. We just half to get this far in the first place. By the way check out Webo a teachable A.I.[Webo a teachable A.I.](http://theshop.hopto.org/chat/)